# Separate specific words from a string in java

Tags: java, string

Is there any way to split the words from a string in `java`?.

```
String my ="StackOverFlow PF Apple FT Laptop HW."
```

PF = Platform, FT = Fruit, HW = Hardware.

The expected output should be

```
StackOverFlow  is a Platform.
Apple  is a Fruit.
Laptop is a hardware.
```

I am doing in this way:

```
String[] words = my.split(" ");
  for(int u=0 ; u<words.length ; u++){
      System.out.println( words(u));
  }
```

Comment: Yes.  You write code to split the string.  Then you check the results for matches, and change the words accordingly.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Should I remove all the spaces first?

Comment: you could just do something like `String[] words = my.split(" ");` which creates an array that contains each word without a space, as per the token passed in.

Comment: You use the spaces FOR the split.  Like @Orin2005 suggested.

Comment: The "dummy" output you're referring to is exactly what you should expect. When you tell it to print an array, it's going to print the details of that array (memory location, etc...). Instead, you should loop through each element of the array and print the value of the element

Comment: What about the period at the end?

Comment: @shmosel Just ignore.

Comment: Ignore what? All periods? All end characters? All abbreviations with more than 2 characters? All punctuation?

Comment: @durbnpoisn it is not finding `HW` in the string array .`String[] words = my.split(" ");
  for(int u=0 ; u<words.length ; u++){
   if(words[u].equals("HW")){
    System.out.println( words[u]);
   }
  }`

Comment: @shmosel ignore all the periods.

Comment: @user6750923 - it's because the split would leave "HW."  The period is with it.

Comment: @durbnpoisn OMG. I reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Fields
        String myString = "StackOverFlow PF Apple FT Laptop HW";

        String[] tokens = myString.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(tokens[i]);
            // Every other token
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print(" is a " + convert(tokens[i + 1]));
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    /**
     * convert method turns the abbreviations into long form
     */
    private static String convert(String s) {
        String str;
        switch (s) {
            case "PF":
                str = "Platform";
                break;
            case "FT":
                str = "Fruit";
                break;
            case "HW":
                str = "Hardware";
                break;
            default:
                str = "Unknown";
                break;
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the values will be in the above order, something like this should work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String my = "StackOverflow PF Apple FT Laptop HW";
    String[] words = my.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(words(i) + " is a ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(getTranslation(words(i)));
        }
    }
}

private String getTranslation(String code) {
    if ("PF".equals(code)) {
        return "Platform";
    }
    //etc...
}
```

Essentially, what this will do is split the string into all of the words. Since the words are "paired" together, they will come in groups of 2. This means that you can check if the index for the word is even or odd. If it's even, then you know it's the 1st paired word meaning you can append the "is a " string to it. If it's odd, then you want to append the translated value.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex amd split the hole text in groups of 2 words...

then split every element of the array by spaces and you are done!

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
String inputTxt = "StackOverFlow PF Apple FT Laptop HW.";
String[] elements = inputTxt.split("(?<!\\G\\w+)\\s");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elements));
System.out.println(elements[0].split(" ")[0] + " is a Platform");
System.out.println(elements[1].split(" ")[0] + " is a Fruit");
System.out.println(elements[2].split(" ")[0] + " is a Hardware");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited specification in your question, there's no reason to split. You can just replace your placeholders like this:

```
String my = "StackOverFlow PF Apple FT Laptop HW.";
my = my.replaceAll("PF[\\s.]?", "  is a Platform.\n");
my = my.replaceAll("FT[\\s.]?", "  is a Fruit.\n");
my = my.replaceAll("HW[\\s.]?", " is a hardware.\n");
System.out.print(my);
```

Output:

```
StackOverFlow   is a Platform.
Apple   is a Fruit.
Laptop  is a hardware.
```